# Should I buy one of the starter sets, or the core books?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, new-gm

I am a new d&d player, who has some research into d&d. I have decided to try it out, but I don't know which one to buy. (I'm deciding to become a dm for the sake of the new players) Should I get the essentials kit, starters set, or the core books and a free campaign?

Comment: Here are some potential duplicates: [What do the core three books provide that is not already in the Basic Rules, SRD, and free supplements?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94387) [What resources are really needed to start 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/74672) [Starting with D&D: Starter Set vs Dungeon Master's Guide](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159974)

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know there were already answers, will look there

Comment: If you feel like something is missing for you in those Q&As, please let us know.

Comment: More related Q&As: [I'm completely new to D&D. How do I get started with the D&D Starter Set?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112196), [What do I need to run a D&D 5E campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56252)

Comment: Hey, no need to delete this. It's a good question, nothing wrong with it being a duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.